# Stop a script on a single page

Tags: plugins, javascript

I have a plugin that is no longer being supported, and it has an issue with moving a block to the end of a page. Globally this works fine, but on specific pages, I want to disable this script d=froi running so the code stays inline vs being moved to the end.

Here is the script:

```
(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ( $('body').hasClass('single') ) {
                var wppr = $('.wppr-review-container'),
                    ed_tags = $('.expand-divi-below-tags');
                if ( wppr.length && ed_tags.length ) {
                    wppr.insertBefore(ed_tags);
                }
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

What would be the best way to stop .wppr-review-container from being moved to .expand-divi-below-tags?

Answer (score 0):

In the body classes you shoud also find a class corresponding to the page id

(i.e. `<body class=".. page-id-161"`>)
In this case  you can modify your script:

```
(function($) {
  //create array of classes for pages where to exclude the .wppr-review-container from being moved
  var toExclude=['page-id-161','page-id-162','page-id-163'];

  // get all the <body> classes  
  var elementClasses = jQuery("body").attr("class").split(" ");

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < elementClasses.length; i++) {
      // run only if the current page has class single ( per your script) AND IS NOT among the array toExclude
      if($('body').hasClass('single') && jQuery.inArray(elementClasses[i], toExclude) ===-1) {
        var wppr = jQuery('.wppr-review-container'),
        ed_tags = jQuery('.expand-divi-below-tags');
        if ( wppr.length && ed_tags.length ) {
          wppr.insertBefore(ed_tags);
        }
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```